# Usage and grammar points involving 嚟講

Tags: grammar, usage, cantonese

I would like to request for some insights on the usage of the phrase “… 嚟講”.

I have heard this being used in so many ways, one being “對我嚟講” as speaking for myself.

What could be other possible uses and please provide grammar points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

對我嚟講 is Cantonese for 對我來說 in Mandarin

[對]我[來說]， = [for] me, (from my standpoint,)

Example:

對我來說，錢不重要 (對我嚟講，錢唔重要) = for me, money is not important

對他來說，名譽大於一切 (對佢嚟講，名譽大於一切) = For him, fame is more than anything

對他們來說，結婚害多於利 (對佢地嚟講， 結婚害多於利)= For them, getting married does more harm than good

Notice:

The correct character for 嚟 is 來 even in Cantonese (來 read as 嚟)

"對[n]嚟講， + statement " = "for [n], + statement"

The most common usage of this phrase is as 1. a declaration phrase that introduces a statement to follow. 2. a topic marker that marks the noun in it as the topic

Comment: Would there be other uses/contexts involving the said phrase? Please include some usage points as well.

Comment: @cgo See my edition

Comment: Usage points? Use it as you would for IMHO - "In My Humble Opinion"

Comment: @Wayne Cheah "對[n]嚟講" is more than that, e.g. 對犬類來說，巧克力是致命的毒物；對美國來說，要打敗俄軍祇是舉手之勞

Comment: Perhaps I should have said the usage point for “對我嚟講”